# Need help understanding an algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public static int mystery (int m, int n){
    if (n==0||n==m)
        return 1;
    return mystery (m-1, n) + mystery(m-1, n-1);
}
```

This is the algorithm, when calling mystery (7, 5), the output is 21. I'm just not sure how this algorithm works, any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Use pencil and paper and play computer.

Comment: mystery(7,5) = mystery(6,5) + mystery(6,4) = ... go on :)

Comment: I understand that, what i don't understand is how the output is 21. Shouldn't it be 1, since the base case will return 1? I'm confused at this, it should be simple but I can't grasp what's happening here.

Comment: It's adding all the calls together, there's a simple case that would return 1 but your example isn't it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this algorithm is a typical example of Recursion. There is a very simple example to explain it: take two mirrors and place the in front of each other - what will you see? An infinite number of mirrors: so here is the same. While the condition is false the function call its self again and again until the 'n' is 0 or is equal to 'm'.

Open Excel and go step by step counting it by yourself.
Does this answer your question?

Comment: I understand that, what i don't understand is how the output is 21. Shouldn't it be 1, since the base case will return 1? I'm confused at this, it should be simple but I can't grasp what's happening here.

Comment: @Fredamabob: The base case returns 1 but the whole recursive call tree is summing up all the base cases.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Oh.. I feel stupid for not catching that, I understand now.

Comment: But... what is more interesting i run that code in Xamarin Studio for OSX and I received...Stack Overflow :D

Answer (score -1):

It's just the math of recursive definition.

```
M(7, 5) = M(6, 5) + M(6, 4)
M(6, 5) = M(5, 5) + M(5, 4) = 1 + M(5, 4)
M(6, 4) = M(5, 4) + M(5, 3)
M(5, 4) = M(4, 4) + M(4, 3) = 1 + M(4, 3)
M(5, 3) = M(4, 3) + M(4, 2)
M(4, 3) = M(3, 3) + M(3, 2) = 1 + M(3, 2)
M(4, 2) = M(3, 2) + M(3, 1)
M(3, 2) = M(2, 2) + M(2, 1) = 1 + M(2, 1)
M(3, 1) = M(2, 1) + M(2, 0) = M(2, 1) + 1
M(2, 1) = M(1, 1) + M(1, 0) = 1 + 1 = 2
```

Now we can "unwind" the recursion, substituting to find the answer:

```
M(3, 1) = M(2, 1) + M(2, 0) = M(2, 1) + 1 = 2 + 1 = 3
M(3, 2) = M(2, 2) + M(2, 1) = 1 + M(2, 1) = 1 + 2 = 3
M(4, 2) = M(3, 2) + M(3, 1) = 3 + 3 = 6
M(4, 3) = M(3, 3) + M(3, 2) = 1 + M(3, 2) = 1 + 3 = 4
M(5, 3) = M(4, 3) + M(4, 2) = 4 + 6 = 10
M(5, 4) = M(4, 4) + M(4, 3) = 1 + M(4, 3) = 1 + 4 = 5
M(6, 4) = M(5, 4) + M(5, 3) = 5 + 10 = 15
M(6, 5) = M(5, 5) + M(5, 4) = 1 + M(5, 4) = 1 + 5 = 6
M(7, 5) = M(6, 5) + M(6, 4) = 15 + 6 = 21
```

The math I just did is mimicked (roughly) by the recursive calls of the function

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you make a trace through your program to understand what is going on.

Get a piece of paper, and draw a box. Inside that box, write:

```
m = 7, n = 5

Is n == 0 or n == m? (y/n)

return mystery(6,5) + mystery(6,4)
```

Then, draw two boxes below that, with the same data, one for each call to mystery within the function. Repeat until each arrives at the base case.

When you reach the base case of a function, draw an arrow pointing to whatever 'box' called it. Then just sum up your terms.

This method works for every recursive function, and is a powerful tool.